# Is this a GARCH Monte-Carlo simulation?

Tags: monte-carlo, garch

**I tried this as a simulation for a GARCH(1,1) model. Is it correct?** (I'm not speaking about the code itself, which works, but the underlying idea).

Here is plot (of `sigma`, `r` the returns, and the simulated asset price `x`) and Python code:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

n = 1000 * 100
eps = np.random.normal(0, 1, n)
sigma0, a, b, c = 0.0002, 0.0000002, 0.5, 0.4
sigma = np.ones(n) * sigma0
r = np.zeros(n)

for i in range(1,n):
    sigma[i] = np.sqrt(a + b * r[i-1] ** 2 + c * sigma[i-1] ** 2)
    r[i] = sigma[i] * eps[i]

x = np.cumsum(r) + 1.2       # summing the returns; starts at 1.20, see EUR/USD

f, ax = plt.subplots(3)

ax[0].plot(sigma)
ax[1].plot(r)
ax[2].plot(x)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Looks OK to me. (I am not a Python user, but I can more or less follow what the code does.) Also, I think you could edit the title to better reflect the real question here, which seems to be whether the GARCH model (a data generating process) was implemented correctly -- rather than whether what you did is a Monte-Carlo simulation.